# How can I launch Visual Studio via a double-click on a C# script in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio

This is my first time using Unity and I am following the tutorial for the 2D RogueLike Game. Everythings seems to be working properly, apart that I cant get Visual Studio to launch, if I'm double click my c# scripts.

What I have tried so far:

- Checked my preferences, that External Script Editor says "Visual Studio 2017"
- Reinstalled Unity and Visual Studio.

Unity Version: 2019.3.0a2 Personal

Hope somebody can help me.

Additional information:

- After double click, nothing seems to be happening, even my mouse doesnt show a load icon
- When I create a new project, the bug (dont know if bug, or my fault) is still there.
- I can open the .sln file from my project in Visual Studio. Visual Studio can even autocomplete unity based code then, before it was a "miscellaneous file" and didnt autocomplete code like for example "Transform" or "Rigidbody2D".

Comment: This is a good question, and definitely on-topic. Can you tell us if anything happens when you double click a script? If so, edit that into the question.

Comment: Nothing happends. Nothing opens, no errors, nothing I can see.

Comment: Does the same thing happen in a new unity project?

Comment: The same thing happends, so nothing.

Comment: Hi @Christopher, you can try double clicking `.sln` file of your project to see if it opens in Visual studio

Comment: And can you explain a bit about "When I create a new project, the bug (?) is still there" I did not quite understand this, what do you mean by this

Comment: To your first thing, yes I can open the sln file.
To the other thing, Ed Marty wanted to know, if i cant open c# scripts in a completly new project, which yes it still doesnt work. I said "Bug (?)" because I dont know if it is my fault or a real bug.

Comment: Try clicking multiple times

Comment: I spammend my Mouse Button a long time

Comment: Have you tried to "connect to Unity" inside Visual studio? Have you tried with Visual studio 2018 or 2019?

Comment: I dont know what you mean with "Connect to unity".
And know I dont have used visual studio 2018 or 2019, is there a free version as well?

Comment: This seems to be a new problem in this version. I have an existing project that has some script files that I've edited many times in Visual Studio. Since updating to 2019.3.0a2, Unity does nothing when I double click the script files. My advice, don't use an Alpha version of Unity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Package Manager (Window -> Package Manager) and scroll down to Visual Studio Editor. In the lower right corner of the window there should be a button that says something like "Update to 1.0.11". Click that button.

Just to be on the safe side, do the same for Visual Studio Code Editor.

That resolved the issue for me. For some reason, having an outdated package causes Unity to just do nothing. No errors, warnings, or anything. But as soon as I updated I was able to launch Visual Studio by double clicking a script file.